# CustomValidator client side error text not displaying

Tags: javascript, c#

I have the following validator in my WebForms 4.51 application:

```
<asp:CustomValidator ID="cfvClockedOut" runat="server" Display="Static" ControlToValidate="dtpClockedOutAt" CssClass="error" ErrorMessage="" ValidationGroup="Default" ClientValidationFunction="CheckClockOutDate" ValidateEmptyText="True"></asp:CustomValidator>
```

and the associated JS is:

```
function CheckClockOutDate(aSender, aArgs) {
        var ctlClockedOut = $find("<%=dtpClockedOutAt.ClientID %>");
        var ctrlClockedIn = $find("<%=dtpClockedInAt.ClientID %>");

        console.log('Start ' + ctrlClockedIn.get_dateInput().get_selectedDate());
        console.log('End ' + ctlClockedOut.get_dateInput().get_selectedDate());


        //Ensure clocked in is set should clocked out be set
        if (ctrlClockedIn.get_dateInput().get_selectedDate() === null && ctlClockedOut.get_dateInput().get_selectedDate() !== null) {
            console.log('Check');
            aArgs.IsValid = false;
            console.log(aSender.errormessage);
            aSender.errormessage = "Please specify a clock in time.";
            console.log(aSender.errormessage);
            console.log('/Check');
            return;
        }

        console.log('BAIL');
        aArgs.IsValid = true;
    }
```

If I look at what is being displayed in Firebug I see:

```
Start null
End Wed May 06 2015 00:00:00 GMT+1000 (AUS Eastern Standard Time)
Check
undefined
Please specify a clock in time.
/Check
```

so according to the above I am setting the error message to be displayed by the custom validator. However when I look at the corresponding HTML for the error text I see:

```
<span id="ContentPlaceHolder1_cfvClockedOut" class="error" style="visibility:hidden;">
```

so clearly my text has not been updated and hence is not displaying. What am I missing here? Why is my error text not displaying?

Comment: have you tried to add `aArgs.IsValid = false;` after setting the error message?

Comment: Tried that, but it made no difference. In the end I resorted to using jQuery to set the text and show/hide the span containing the error text.